# jQuery - onClick event making elements disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn the basics of jQuery, and to test in one of my sites I've been wanting to add functionality so that onClick it will change the inner text and the href of a hyperlink, my issue, is that when I click on my onClick event, the changes happen, but the onClick button's,  and the href I tried changing dissappears, but my .html functionality works?

*HTML* for onClick -

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: -20px;">
    <div class="gamesdesc">
         <h4 id="gquote" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">test<br><br>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" onClick="$('#my_div').cod4();" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" onClick="$('#my_div').csgo();" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" onClick="$('#my_div').tf2();" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <a id="glinks" href=""><btn class="btn btn-warning">Test</btn></a></h4>
```

*jQuery* -

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.cod4 = function () {
        $("#gquote").html("Test");
        $("glinks").attr("href", "cod4");
    };
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
    $.fn.tf2 = function () {
        $("#gquote").html("Test");
        $("glinks").attr("href", "csgo");
    };
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
    $.fn.csgo = function () {
        $("#gquote").html("Test");
        $("glinks").attr("href", "tf2");
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You should avoid filling in `onclick` attributes, rather use `$("...").click(function(e){...});` inside the `$(document).ready()` handler. Also `$("glinks")` should be `$("#glinks")`. Furthermore you should really learn about function parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes the element disapper because you're changing the html of `gquote` which is the `h4` that containing all the buttons. meaning that everything inside `gquote` disappears and now it contains the text `Test`. either use `.append()` instead of `html()` or change the html of a different element.

and FYI you forgot the `#` at `$("glinks")`